# how to configue vmware workstation 15 to boot a virtual machine from a bootable usb drive

Tags: windows-10, usb, installation, vmware-workstation, bootable-media

I want to try a lot of tutorials as given here [windows tutorials (tutorial index)](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1977-windows-10-tutorial-index.html) 
So I need to prepare a lot of live USB sticks or USB sticks in the formats in which tutorials mention.Most of these tutorials that I want to try are windows installation media creation, creating recovery disks creating custom partitions etc.I want to try them first on virtual machines then want to try the steps on real hardware.I am using Vmware Workstation 15 Pro 15.1.0 build-13591040.
I read a tutorial [here](https://www.virten.net/2014/12/howto-usb-boot-a-vm-in-vmware-workstation-11/) for usb booting in vmware.
Here is how my virtual machine settings look like.
[image: vmware virtual machine boot options settings]
I power on the firmware and see the boot options
[image: boot manager of virtual machine]
configure boot options
[image: configure boot options]
add boot options
[image: add boot options]
No USB boot option
[image: no option to boot from usb]
[image: pci devices listed]
So the question is how do I configure vmware workstation 15 so that I can boot using USB sticks. 
I tried using plop boot ISO also 
I downloaded from this page
https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html

I downloaded package 
https://download.plop.at/files/bootmngr/plpbt-5.0.15.zip​
tried putting it as an ISO to boot

[image: Annotation 2019-12-26 092757.jpg]
[image: Annotation 2019-12-26 092758.jpg]
[image: Annotation 2019-12-26 092759.jpg]

I selected the plpt iso (which is probably plop boot manager ISO)
[image: Annotation 2019-12-26 092760.jpg]

There was no effect of using plpt boot ISO. What next can I try?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - two suggestions:

1. Using the firmware boot options, after you powered on the machine make sure the USB is connected:

   `VM->Removable Devices-><Your USB>->Connect (Disconnect from host)`
2. If that didn't work, plop is a good option. In order to boot from the plop boot manager you should follow the steps in
   [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/97923/how-to-boot-a-vmware-virtual-machine-from-a-usb-drive/) (you need to setup the machine as ubuntu).

Hope it helps

Comment: Plop sometime works well and sometimes not. An alternative is also using VirtualBox (see [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/)).

Answer (score -1):

Add second disk map it to physical usb stick and boot from it